# how to uninstall a plugin when there is no cp option

Tags: plugins, uninstall

I want to uninstall a plugin.
I disabled it in CP but there is no option to uninstall this plugin.

So I go to composer and remove it from the `required` section and run `composer update`.
This deals with the files but not the database record.

So it's not clear to me the best way to uninstall a plugin in Craft 3. Thru the interface is fine when it works but when there is no option how do you get rid of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It isn't possible to uninstall a disabled plugin; you'll need to first enable the plugin, and then the Uninstall option will be available.

The correct way to remove a plugin is actually to first Uninstall it. After uninstalling, you can either run `composer remove vendor/plugin-handle` from the command line, or select the "Remove" option from the Control Panel (the "Remove" option is available for any plugin that isn't currently installed).

If you do it the other way around – i.e. remove the files before uninstalling the plugin – you're probably going to see some issues.