# What's the correct way to uninstall a plugin which MUST NOT be enabled?

Tags: plugins, uninstall

I hadn't allowed Craft to update for a while, and then did, but it broke on a plugin, and I couldn't get into the CP. I figured out which plugin was causing the problem, it turned out I wasn't using it, so I disabled it in `craft/config/general.php` as follows:

```
return [
    '*' => [
        'disabledPlugins' => ['embedded-assets-link'],
    ],
];
```

That enabled me access to the CP, but, being disabled, I couldn't uninstall it through the CP, as explained [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26897/how-to-uninstall-a-plugin-when-there-is-no-cp-option?rq=1).

I tried many things, including

- remove references to the plugin in `craft/vendor/craftcms/plugins.php`
- removed references to the plugin from `composer.json`
- run `composer update`

and probably some other nonsense.

So, having done it the hard way, I'd like to ask, is there a correct way to remove a plugin which cannot be enabled ('cause it's broken) ?

Comment: I think you can use one single command `composer remove vendor/package/name` as you have the access of SSH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to enable it to uninstall it but you can do everything via CLI.

First `./craft plugin/enable plugin-handle` then `./craft plugin/uninstall plugin-handle` then `composer remove namespace/package-name`.

If you really can't enable it as above, you'd need to `composer remove namespace/package-name` and manually remove any references in your `plugins` table, project config as well as any tables the plugin may have created on install.

Comment: Thank you. After posting, it dawned on me that, as you mention, without enabling the plugin, it can't do its own cleanup upon uninstalling.